# Bootstrap nav design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

does anyone know how to achieve this in bootstrap for the nav? Logo on the left and nav on right.

My guess is you use col's with some css?

[image: image here]

Comment: show your code and what you teried so far... And what version of bootstrap

Comment: Coincidently, I was doing something very similar to this yesterday, but I can't see Bootstrap doing anything but get in the way.

Comment: @לבנימלכה I haven't tried it yet as I can't figure it out logic for it.

Comment: @Quentin i believe that you could use a row with a col-4 and a col-8 and change the background colours on each col maybe but its the slash in the middle i cant understand

Comment: @Jenova1628 — It's fairly trivial with clip path, but the Bootstrap conventions on how you do columns get in the way.

Comment: @Quentin have you done this without bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create the section i wanted the code i am using is:

CSS:

```
.menu {
background-color: lightblue;
overflow: hidden;
background-color:white;
}

.menu:after {
content: "";
border-bottom: 850px solid transparent;
border-right: 400px solid #0055b7;
position: absolute;
left: 80%;
top: 0;
}

.nav-menu ul {
list-style: none;
display: inline-flex;
}

.nav-menu ul li {
padding: 40px;
}

.blue-bg {
background-color: #0055b7;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="menu col-md-5">
                          <img class="paddingHeader" src="assets/images/headerlogo.png" /> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="content col-md-7 blue-bg">
                        <div class="nav-menu">
                              <ul>
                                <li><a class="text-white" href="">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a class="text-white" href="">About Us</a></li>
                                <li><a class="text-white" href="">Properties To Let</a></li>
                                <li><a class="text-white" href="">We Buy Houses</a></li>
                                <li><a class="text-white" href="">Contact Us</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```